Wood maxed out at 12 inches
Why is it that in big box stores (Lowes or Home Depot, etc.) you can only buy boards that are maximum 12inch wide. I pulled out of my parents' attic boards that are 16-18 inches wide and 3/4 inch thick. Their house was built in 1924 and I think they are from then.

The simple answer is that there's virtually no need for it in construction — realise this isn't project wood, it's not intended for furniture or anything else like that, it's construction wood, pure and simple. There is however wood available for sale outside of this ecosystem in widths beyond 12" nominal. You just have to go to a lumber yard, or directly to a mill, to find it. If you were after such boards you'd expect to pay a premium — there's a premium for width and length and thickness in the wood world, especially when it's all three together.

The alternative to sourcing very wide boards, in case you don't know, is to glue up two or more narrower boards to make a panel. This has been done for a very long time, even when wider boards were much more common than today, but glueing up to make wide panels is extremely common practice now. It's worth highlighting also that this can actually result in something that's a lot more stable than a single wide board of the same dimensions.

Yep, old growth versus new growth. There's no economic reason to grow trees slow and big anymore.

Boards wider than 12 inches would command a HUGE premium.  A lot of that premium would be due to the relatively small amount of harvested timber from which such boards could be commercially obtained.  Beyond that, the effort and calendar time needed to create 2x16 boards would be long and possibly require a degree of skill not typical of those who produce lumber for box stores.
By the way, a 1924 2x12 would be 2 inches thick and 12 inches wide. a 2024 2x12 is 1.5 inches thick and 11.25 inches wide. It follows that a 2024 2x16 would be no wider than 15.25 inches.  I believe the US standard doesn't go beyond would is referred to as a 2x12.

In addition to the cost (old growth, etc. as described in another answer and in comments), there is the why. Most lumber in construction ends up in two very different uses:

Structural/Framing

For this purpose, narrower boards are almost always sufficient. For many things, 2x4s (1.5" x 3.5", and similar reductions on larger sizes, so only mentioning this once) are sufficient. For a lot of other things, 2x6s are plenty, with occasional larger sizes or doubling up boards for additional strength.
For the really big stuff - large support beams running the length or width of a house and supporting the floor above (sometimes two floors), engineered lumber is used. This often (think I-beams) uses a lot less actual wood than a single piece of wood would require, is manufactured from smaller pieces (so no huge old trees are needed) and can actually be more structurally stable than a single piece of wood. These beams are often used where the alternative would be an equivalent steel beam.

Big Flat Stuff

I am sure there is a proper term, but I don't know what it is. But where in the old days they would use wide 3/4" thick boards, now we use 3/4" thick plywood (or sometimes other things like OSB). Plywood (and OSB, etc.) typically is manufactured in 8' x 4' sheets, sometimes even larger. The important thing is that 4' wide plywood doesn't actually need 4' wide trees, so it can efficiently cover large areas without required big (and old) trees. This works for floors, roofs, sometimes walls and other things. Plywood is available in various thicknesses, so if you don't need 3/4" you can get 1/2" or even thinner, picking the thickness (and therefore the cost) to match the requirements.
